# calling function that is in different modules python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing many small python scripts and keeping in one directory and i am calling them in different scripts

Below is the script and it is calling function that has saved in another director acc_repo:

```
from acc_repo import col
import logging
import getpass
col.col()
dc = raw_input(OKGREEN + "Choose DataCenter:" + ENDC)
    File "ucs_qa.py", line 21, in <module>
    dc = raw_input(OKGREEN + "Choose DataCenter:" + ENDC)
NameError: name 'OKGREEN' is not defined
```

function that is saved in acc_repo directory

```
def col ():
    global HEADER
    global OKBLUE
    global OKGREEN
    global WARNING
    global FAIL
    global ENDC
    global BOLD
    global UNDERLINE
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
```

How do i fix the error? Is i am in right track in terms handling many small python scripts. Please advice and help to fix the issue

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: Where is `OKGREEN` defined? You need to import it from there.

Comment: Try `col()` instead of `col.col()`

Comment: col() not working and OKGREEN is saved in function and saved in different directory

Comment: I highly recommend checking this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python) out. If you can get around using global variables I would advise that.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
col.OKGREEN
```

Just like functions, variables in different files need to know where they reside in. This allows developers to create same named variables without bothering what library they are importing.

Answer (score 0):

Your function col.col() declares global variables, but they are still in the scope of the module in which they are declared.  So after calling `col.col()`, you can access the declared variables by qualifying the name with the `col` module.  For example, you can access `OKGREEN` with `col.OKGREEN`

Answer (score 0):

(updated the answer)
Try this:

```
from acc_repo import col
import logging
import getpass

col.col()

# import the OKGREEN.. etc after col()
from acc_repo.col import * 

dc = raw_input(OKGREEN + "Choose DataCenter:" + ENDC)
```

The global variables are intialized after col() is called.

---

But this is more like a fast workaround to make your code work. I guess you tried to make the global variables "global" in main.py by calling `col()`, but they are actually only global in the scope of col.py. Therefore, the `from acc_repo.col import *` is still necessary after `col()` is called.

To achieve what you want, modify col.py to (as @Maurice's answer):

```
HEADER = '\033[95m'
OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
WARNING = '\033[93m'
FAIL = '\033[91m'
ENDC = '\033[0m'
BOLD = '\033[1m'
UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
```

then remove the line `col.col()`, and keep the other as they are.

Comment: File "ucs_qa.py", line 20, in <module>
    col()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

Dont use global variables at all !

acc_repo.py:

```
HEADER = '\033[95m'
OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
WARNING = '\033[93m'
FAIL = '\033[91m'
ENDC = '\033[0m'
BOLD = '\033[1m'
UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
```

main.py:

```
from acc_repo import *
import logging
import getpass

dc = raw_input(OKGREEN + "Choose DataCenter:" + ENDC)
print(dc)
```